How can I improve these reinforcement learning reward functions?
I am working for the very first time to a RL problem. More in details, I am working with a 3DOF model of a buisness jet aircraft. The environement is made up by the aircraft model + the two PID controllers that control the pitch angle and the thrust. The goal is to develop a RL agent that builds the correct policy, that is the commanded pitch and the commanded thrust so that the aircraft will accelerate to a setpoint, keeping the altitude constant as much as possible. The idea is that the RL Agent has to behave like the TECS Core Algorithm in the classic control theory applications; it must manage the total energy of the aircraft to keep the airspeed response and the altitude response separed.
As observations I have considered the reference signals of the airspeed, the altitude, the energy rate and the distribution energy rate at three different instants of time plus the tracking error.
The actions span within the range [-1, 1] and then they are "de-normalized" to their actual value in this way


I am trying to train a DDPG Agent in Matlab/Simulink. The reward shaping is made in this way:

The last actions are strongly penalized when they fall in the saturation range. I have exploited the barrierPenalty as it comes in MatLab


The idea is to encourage the agent to explore the action space but still penalizing it when it saturates because the answer is not there for sure.

The airspeed reward function is build taking into account that we want the aircraft to accelerate toward a given setpoint but with a given dynamics, i.e. I have some requirements in terms of overshoot/undershoot and rise time/settling time. So I have build a "box" in the airspeed-time space and when the airspeed response falls within this box, the penalty is zero otherwhise there is a penalty. At this moment, I am exploiting the barrierPenalty function and the behaviour with a test response is the following


This is an "on-off" behavior, so when the response is far behind the box the penalty goes to the maximum whereas when it is inside the penalty depends on how far it is from the setpoint, as you can see here


The altitude follows a similar approach to the airspeed one. I have build a "safe box" around the trimmed altitude, but now I have just a rectangular shape since I want just to be around that value




So far we have just penalties, so to encourage the agent to keep going I have introduced a bonus proportional to the aircraft acceleration normalized by the gravity plus a constant reward. Eventually, I get this
$ \text{Total reward} = K_a*\frac{\dot{V}}{g} + \text{Airspeed penalty} + \text{Altitude penalty} + \text{Actions penalty} + 25*\frac{\text{Agent sample time}}{\text{Final simulation time}}$
Despite all this strategy, the agent contiunes to collect negative rewards over more than 600 episodes and during most of them the actions always start from the saturation area (so -1, 1).
In your opinion, this may be a problem related to reward shaping or to some settings of the agent (exploration - exploitation)? How can I improve the rewards?
Thank you

This approach isn't working at all; my agent isn't learning. If you have any suggestions or advice, please let me know.
